# Does vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer work when source image uses VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL?

Tags: vulkan

I have read (after running into the limitation myself) that for copying data from the host to a `VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL` **VkImage**, you're better off using a **VkBuffer** rather than a VkImage for the staging image to avoid restrictions on mipmap and layer counts. ([Here](http://xlgames-inc.github.io/posts/vulkantips/) and [Here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/926085/texture-memory-management/))

So, when it came to implementing a `glReadPixels`-esque piece of functionality to read the results of a render-to-texture back to the host, I thought that reading to a staging VkBuffer with `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` instead of using a staging VkImage would be a good idea.

However, I haven't been able to get it to work yet, I'm seeing most of the intended image, but with rectangular blocks of the image in incorrect locations and even some bits duplicated.

There is a good chance that I've messed up my synchronization or layout transitions somewhere and I'll continue to investigate that possibility.

However, I couldn't figure out from the spec whether using `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` with an image source using `VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL` is actually supposed to 'un-tile' the image, or whether I should actually expect to receive a garbled implementation-defined image layout if I attempt such a thing.

So my question is: Does `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` with a `VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL` source image fill the buffer with linearly tiled data or optimally (implementation defined) tiled data?

Comment: FWIW, I have fixed my bug and vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer is now working as expected. My staging buffer memory allocator was returning a structure that included the VkBuffer, an offset into the VkBuffer, and a memory mapped pointer. The memory mapped pointer was already to a pointer to my specific resource (offset was already applied). My bug was that I was adding the offset to the memory mapped pointer a second time when using it as the source for the memcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 18.4](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#copies-buffers-images) describes the layout of the data in the source/destination buffers, relative to the image being copied from/to. This is outlined in the description of the `VkBufferImageCopy` struct. There is no language in this section which would permit different behavior from tiled images.

The specification even has pseudo code for how copies work (this is for non-block compressed images):

```
rowLength = region->bufferRowLength;
if (rowLength == 0)
    rowLength = region->imageExtent.width;

imageHeight = region->bufferImageHeight;
if (imageHeight == 0)
    imageHeight = region->imageExtent.height;

texelSize = <texel size taken from the src/dstImage>;

address of (x,y,z) = region->bufferOffset + (((z * imageHeight) + y) * rowLength + x) * texelSize;

where x,y,z range from (0,0,0) to region->imageExtent.width,height,depth}.
```

The `x,y,z` part is the location of the pixel in question from the image. Since this location is not dependent on the tiling of the image (as evidenced by the lack of anything stating that it would be), buffer/image copies will work equally on both kinds of tiling.

Also, do note that this specification is *shared* between `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` and `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage`. As such, if a copy works one way, it by necessity must work the other.

Comment: What about the alignment of the texels? I can't find anything about it in the standard.

Comment: Turns out even the spec writers are puzzled about it: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/752#issuecomment-410915770, but it seems each row is aligned to a multiple of `4` bytes, which follows the default `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of OpenGL.

Comment: Except for depth/stencil formats, where the the data is **mostly** tightly packed according to the Vulkan standard.

Comment: @plasmacel: The issue you link to has been resolved. The Vulkan text and pseudo code are very clear about the meaning of all of these values; [there is no "alignment" in terms of some required row size](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/776#issuecomment-419954382). Compressed images have to specify sizes in multiples of blocks, but that's normal.